# Issues with private key / password and git repository on my Media Temple (dv) server

Tags: git, ssh, private-key

I set up a git repository on my Media Temple (dv) server to start managing and deploying web projects more easily but I'm running into a wall. When trying to clone the remote repository to my local machine (using SmartGit or the console) I'm being asked for the private key file and/or the password. The specific message is:

> Provide the credentials for authenticating to the SSH server
>   'git.website.com' as user 'Brandon'.

I already followed the instructions [laid out here](http://kb.mediatemple.net/questions/1626/Using+SSH+keys+on+your+server) for uploading my Public Key. I thought this would solve this issue, but it hasn't. I've tried every password I have in this account, but to no avail.

Suggestions?

**UPDATE 1**

Here is what I'm doing in Terminal that leads me to the Password road block:

```
$ cd /Users/.../project_name
$ git remote add web ssh://git.website.com/project_name.git
$ git push web +master:refs/heads/master
```

And this leads to this message:

```
Brandon@git.website.com's password:
```

**UPDATE 2**

Here is a screenshot of the SmartGit screen, if it helps. http://cloud.smallparade.com/Cpck

Comment: What's your client OS, how are you cloning your repository? Please provide exact commands and their output, it will help a great deal.

Comment: I'm running Mac OSX Lion. In Terminal I was trying to set up the local environment and add the remote address when I ran into the Password issue. The I just tried to clone using SmartGit and, again, was hit with the Public Key/Password question.

Comment: Added Terminal commands above.

Comment: Also worth noting, "Brandon" is the current OSX account I'm logged in as.

Comment: What is your username _on the server_? You should put it in `ssh://username@git.website.com/` . The identity file should be your `~/.ssh/id_rsa` file.

Comment: It sounds like the keys just didn't get set up properly. It's a little bit difficult & might take a couple of tries, but go through the set up again.

Comment: J-16 SDiZ - If you add that as an answer I'll accept it. It wasn't the keys... it was the URL and username I had wrong. The keys were actually set up correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to have a SSH problem, not a git problem.  First, troubleshoot it by taking git out of the equation.

Assuming you have an actual shell account on this machine, type this:

ssh git.website.com

If it prompts you for a password, then you did not upload your public key correctly.

Type in your password, log in, and then check out .ssh/authorized_keys to see what may be wrong.  If you had done it right, your key is the last one in the file (likely the only one).  If it's not there or the file doesn't exist, you did something wrong.

If your password doesn't work, you have a bigger problem.  Talk to your server tech support.

Answer (score -1):

Change the repo permissions. 
For exemplo: chmod -R 755

Comment: this answer is irrelevant to the question